# How to assign different public IP addresses for different Wireguard peers?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I want to use **different public IP addresses** for each peer in my Wireguard network. Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to bind a WireGuard server configuration to a IP address, it is only possible to set a different port with the `ListenPort` option. This means a configuration will always listen on all the available interfaces of the machine.

If you VPN server has all the public IP address available, you can connect every peer to a different public IP address by specifying a different `Endpoint` in the peer configuration.

A other option would be to have a router in front of the VPN server and using `destination NAT` or `port forwarding`, route every public IP address to the VPN server.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the best way but you can create two Wireguard configs and change the
interface value:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.1.5/24
Address = 0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
ListenPort = 8965
```

So the Wireguard will listen/use the Address you have selected.